# QML/Qt creator inverte selected PathView circle item position

Tags: qt, qml

I can't figure out how to change the current index position from center-left to center-right. I have 20 items arranged in a circle, and the selected item is currently positioned in the left vertical center of the path.

I want the selected item always to be positioned in the right vertical center of the path. I have already managed to invert the first item from left to right using this line: `currentIndex: pathView.count / 2 // invert the 1st to right`.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    visible: true
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    color: "black"
    
    Rectangle {
        id: wheelposition
        width: parent.width / 2
        height: parent.height
        anchors.left: parent.left
        color: "white"
        
        PathView {
            id: pathView
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.width
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter // Center vertically
            focus: true
            Keys.onUpPressed: decrementCurrentIndex()
            Keys.onDownPressed: incrementCurrentIndex()
            model: 20 // 20 icons
            // currentIndex: pathView.count - 1 // Start from (last index)
            currentIndex: pathView.count / 2  // invert the 1st to right
            
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: (pathView.width / pathView.count) * 0.8 // Adjust size based on the width of the PathView
                height: 50
                color: index === pathView.currentIndex  ? "red" : "blue" // Change color if item is selected or not
                
                Text {
                    text: index + 1 // Display index as text
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                    color: index === pathView.currentIndex ? "white" : "black" // Change text color if item is selected
                }
                
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        // Handle item click
                        console.log("Clicked on item " + (index + 1));
                        pathView.currentIndex = index; // Set the current index to the clicked item
                    }
                }
                
                // x: index === pathView.currentIndex ? 0 : pathView.width - width
                    
                transform: [
                    Rotation {
                        origin.x: width / 2
                        origin.y: height / 2
                        axis { x: 0; y: 0; z: 1 }
                        angle: ((index + pathView.currentIndex) * (360))
                    },
                    Translate {  // moves circle left / right and up / down
                        x: pathView.width / 2 // Offset to center items
                        y: pathView.height / 2 // Offset to center items
                    }
                ]
            }
            
            path: Path {
                startX: 0
                startY: 0
                PathSvg {
                    path: "M " + (pathView.width / 6) + " 0" + " a " + (pathView.width / 2) + " " + (pathView.height / 2) + " 0 1 0 " + pathView.width + " 0" + " a " + (pathView.width / 2) + " " + (pathView.height / 2) + " 0 1 0 -" + pathView.width + " 0"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use a [PathAngleArc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-pathanglearc.html), you can play with the `startAngle` to get the desired starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've over-engineered your problem. The transform is not needed. The problem you're having is the `startX` and `startY` and the SVG geometry needs to be rewritten to fit your purpose.

To unpack the problem, let's start with a square that roughly corresponds to points that you would have in your circle:

```
PathSvg {
    startX: pathView.width
    startY: pathView.height / 2
    PathSvg {
        property int w: pathView.width
        property int h: pathView.height
        path: `
M ${w} ${h/2}
L ${w/2} ${h}
L 0 ${h/2}
L ${w/2} 0
L ${w} ${h/2}
`
    }
}
```

In the above, because I leverage from Javascript string interpolation I was able to improve the readability and maintainability of your SVG. Here you'll see that the SVG now begins on the center-right, i.e. `${w} ${h/2}` and it navigates itself clockwise. Also, I switched from relative to absolute SVG coordinates so that you'll see that:

- center-right is: `${w} ${h/2}`
- bottom-center: `${w/2} ${h}`
- center-left: is `0 ${h/2}`
- top-center: `${w/2} 0`

Now that this works, we can replace straight lines with arcs to build your circle:

```
Path {
    startX: pathView.width
    startY: pathView.height / 2
    PathSvg {
        property int w: pathView.width
        property int h: pathView.height
        property int rx: pathView.width / 2
        property int ry: pathView.height / 2
        path: `
M ${w} ${h/2}
A ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1 ${w/2} ${h}
A ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1 0 ${h/2}
A ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1 ${w/2} 0
A ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1 ${w} ${h/2}
`
    }
}
```

Below is a working example that applies the above `PathSvg` to the `PathView`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    title: "PathView circle starting center-right"
    Rectangle {
        id: wheelposition
        width: Math.min(parent.width, parent.height) / 2
        height: width
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "white"
        border.color: "black"
        
        PathView {
            id: pathView
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: parent.width * 0.8
            height: parent.height * 0.8
            focus: true
            model: 20 
            currentIndex: 0
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: (pathView.width / pathView.count) * 0.8
                height: 50
                color: index === pathView.currentIndex  ? "red" : "blue"                
                Text {
                    text: index + 1
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                    color: index === pathView.currentIndex ? "white" : "lightgray"
                }
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: pathView.currentIndex = index
                }
            }
            
            path: Path {
                startX: pathView.width
                startY: pathView.height / 2
                PathSvg {
                    property int w: pathView.width
                    property int h: pathView.height
                    property int rx: pathView.width / 2
                    property int ry: pathView.height / 2
                    path: `
M ${w} ${h/2}
A ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1 ${w/2} ${h}
A ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1 0 ${h/2}
A ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1 ${w/2} 0
A ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1 ${w} ${h/2}
`
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Thanks, was missing this to my PathView preferredHighlightBegin : 0.5
preferredHighlightEnd: preferredHighlightBegin and pathItemCount: 12 for it only show 12 not all my 700 items.  thanks a lot for show me a diferent way to do it